# How do I print this specific pyramid in Java?

Tags: java

I desire a code output that looks like this:

```
6 5 4 3 2 1
5 4 3 2 1
4 3 2 1
3 2 1
2 1
1
```

Keep in mind that my code takes in the size of the pyramid through input before

My code now looks like:

```
for(int numRows=sizePyr;numRows>=1;numRows--){
    for(int i=sizePyr;i>=numRows;i--){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: the nested for loop should be `for(int i=numRows;i>=1;i--)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the nested for loop to `for (int i = numRows; i >= 1; i--)` fixed the issue

You want to start printing i with the current numRows value, then work the way down to 1.

Your current code start printing i with sizePyr (which is a constant 6 throughout the function), then work the way down to numRows.

```
    for(int numRows=sizePyr;numRows>=1;numRows--){
        for(int i=numRows; i >= 1; i--){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

For the first line, you want to start with `sizePyr` (as your inner loop does), but want to *end* with 1 (which your loop decidedly does *not*).  In fact, *every* line should end with 1.  Change your loop to reflect this.